# How to override the style of an ionic component with styled-components

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, styled-components

I have this Ionic tabbar that I want to custom :

```
<IonTabBar>...</IonTabBar>
```

If I override the component like this...

```
const TabBar = styled(IonTabBar)`
  font-family : 'Montserrat';
`

<IonTab>...</IonTab>
```

... I get this error :

```
Uncaught Error: IonTabs needs a IonTabBar
    at IonTabs.render ...
```

Why ?
Do I absolutely need to create a div container to custom the style ?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like there's a similar problem and workaround on github.
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/21541